# NativeScript full screen webview without bounce

Tags: nativescript

How can i make a webView in NativeScript fullscreen including the statusbar. Not hide the statusbar only but the webview behind the statusbar like do this cordova.

And how can i prevent the webview of scrolling/bouncing

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

What i mean with the statusbar/fullscreen and cordova is in cordova is the statusbar transparent and the web view fullscreen.

[image]

and the other question is about the bouncing, in cordova can i prevent the webview from bouncing with this in the config.xml

```
<preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
```

**Update:**

The solution for the bounce is this:

```
var webView = page.getViewById('webView');
webView.ios.scrollView.bounces = false
```

How can make the statusbar transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was on the end.

ios:

put this in the plist file to make the statusbar "transparent"

```
<key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
<string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
```

create a ios only file with this content to but the webview under the status bar

```
#webView{
  margin-top: -20;
}
```

and add this to the page loaded function to prevent the webview of bouncing

```
 if(page.ios){
      webView.ios.scrollView.bounces = false
  }
```

android:

is much simpler but this in the page wrapper of the webview to hide the titlebar

```
actionBarHidden="true"
```

i hope this helps anyone

Comment: Be advised that in some cases that the iOS status ca be doubled in hight, such as when network sharing or an ongoing call is active (the blue/green bar). No idea how to poll for that.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not following your question in regards to the statusbar and Cordova. However for the bouncing, the simplest option is to use this plugin which already has the native code for both iOS/android to remove the scroll bounce. See here: https://github.com/TheOriginalJosh/nativescript-swiss-army-knife#common-functions

If you can expand a bit more about what you want to do with the statusbar I can help there. I have a blog post detailing the android statusbar and navigation bar and a few things you can do natively with it in a few lines of code. https://bradmartin.net/2016/03/10/fullscreen-and-navigation-bar-color-in-a-nativescript-android-app/